# Where is my firebase serviceAccountCredentials.json file

Tags: node.js, firebase

Trying to setup Firebase in Node and I need the serviceAccountCredentials.json which the docs say you just download from the console.

I have searched the console and can't for the life of me find where this would be.

Can anyone point me as to where I get this?

Comment: It's in the Firebase Console once you go to the permissions panel. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app